# a good scalable back-end (CMS), what do you recommend

Tags: content-management-system

Would love to hear your suggestion about what to use.
What is important is:

1. For our front-end we use VueJS.
2. Back-end we prefer Laravel or Lumen
3. Multiple customers will use it so it should be easy to upgrade
4. High maintainable and scalable

If you have any experience with a nice CMS that we can use then I would be more then happy to hear your thoughts about it and why you would recommend it.

I did a lot of searching on Google but it is quite hard to get a good answer.

Mainly it will be used to edit text, add photo's et cetera, a little bit like the back-end (CMS) that Wordpress has. Option to add HTML elements and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using WordPress and its REST API on the backend, then you can use whatever you want on the front end (e.g. VueJS).

For Laravel, you can consider October.  But I can't offer an advantage to that over just using WordPress's REST API.

For something new, consider not running a backend CMS at all -- try https://tipe.io